# How to simplify this query with sql joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql

my_table has 4 columns: `id integer, value integer, value2 integer, name character varying`

I want all the records that:

1. have the same value2 as a record which name is 'a_name'
2. have a field value inferior to the one of a record which name is 'a_name'

And I have satisfying results with the following query:

```
select t.id 
from my_table as t
where  t.value < ( select value from my_table where name = 'a_name')
and s.value2 = (select value2 from my_table where name = 'a_name');
```

But **is it possible to simplify this query with sql joins ?**

Joining on the same table is still too much intricate in my mind. And I try to understand with this example.

What I happened so far trying, is a result full of dupplicates:

```
select t2.id 
from my_table as t
inner join my_table as t2 on t2.value2 = t.value2
where t2.value < ( select value from my_table where name = 'a_name');
```

Comment: Looking at the first query, it looks like for each group of records with the same value2, it eliminates the record with the largest `t.value`?  Would be good if you showed example data in the table, and then example desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem.

```
select t1.id
from my_table as t1
join my_table as t2 
  on t1.value2 = t2.value2
  and t2.name = 'a_name'
  and t1.value < t2.value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always get distinct results by calling "SELECT distinct t2.id ..."

However, that will not enhance your understanding of inner joins. If you are willing, keep reading on. Let's start by getting all records with name = 'a_name'.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM my_table as a
WHERE a.name = 'a.name';
```

A simpler way to perform your inner joins is to understand that the result for the above query is yet another table, formally known as a [relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28database%29). You can think of it as joining on the same table, but an easier way to think of it is as "joining on the result of this query". Lets put this to the test.

```
SELECT other.id
FROM my_table as a,
INNER JOIN my_table as other ON other.value2 = a.value2
WHERE a.name = 'a_name'
AND other.value < a.value;
```

If the first query (all rows with name = 'a_name') has many results, you stand a good chance of the second query having duplicates, because the inner join between aliases 'a' and 'other' is a subset of their [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Edits: Grammar, Clarity

Answer (score 1):

You should use self join instead of inner join see this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: JOIN is the same as INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
select t.id 
from my_table as t
inner join
(select value from my_table where name = 'a_name')t1 on t.value<t1.value
inner join 
(select value2 from my_table where name = 'a_name')t2 on t.value2=t2.value2
```